# jQuery .val() not returning full text from a dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if someone could help me with a simple question?
i have a dropdown list when i select an item, i want to get the value from it using jquery.
I use the .val() method, but the issue is the items value has a space in it such as "Type A"
and it only returns "Type" leaving out the A. I want the full text how could i accomplish this?

**Updated code:**

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<categories>
<category type='Type A'>
    <genre>1</genre>
    <genre>2</genre>
</category>
<category type='Type B'>
     <genre>3</genre>
     <genre>4</genre>
     <genre>5</genre>
</category>
<category type='Type C'>
    <genre>6</genre>
</category>
</categories>
```

Full jQuery Code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myxml.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data){
            xml = data;
            });
        }
    });

    return {getXml : function() 
    { 
        if (xml) return xml;
    }};
})();

/* On Category Change */
$(".category").change(function(){
    var type = $(this).val();
    alert(type);
});
```

HTML

```
<select class='category'>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an HTML snippet of the element with the "category" class?

Comment: Works fine for me here http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/vdt3a/

Comment: That's interesting, when I run this code I get the full value. Maybe an unclosed quotation?
By the way, have you tried $(this).attr('value')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `text` and `value`. It sounds like you want the `text` that is visible in the option , not the value of it which is not visible.

```
$(".category").change(function(){
    var type = $(this).val();

    var currSelectedText= $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    alert(currSelectedText);
});
```

Comment: Ya i was trying the text before but i didnt put find option selected so it returned all the text... Why wouldnt the value work though if i set it to the same value as the text?

Comment: value should return whatever is in it regardless of space or not

Comment: Ya thats what i thought but for some reason its not returning the full value but the text is... anyways ill haveto work with the text thats fine also... Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".category").change(function(){
    var type = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to do with your XML formatting.

Try changing

```
type='Type A'
```

To

```
type="Type A"
```

I was having the same issue when I left out the quotes around an attribute in HTML, and also thought it was a jQuery issue with the .val() function.